# Create file on a rails migration

Tags: ruby, file, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations, file-location

I'm trying to generate default images on my database directly on a migration from images included in my rails app (assets/images).

Before this kind of migration, I tap my command directly on the terminal.

I would like something like that :

`File.new('path/to/my/default/avatar')`

I tried with `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path`, `asset_path`, `Rails.root.join`.

If this way is not at all the good one to do what I want, please let me know the best way. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but you might want to use something like [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) so that you can upload images to you models.

You may also want to use a [seed file](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) to add images to your database as migrations should generally be concerned with changes in the database structure rather than actual data.

Comment: I'm using [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to upload images but now I'm just tying to add default avatar (only once) on my database as I've created some users (that's to say in a migration). But maybe it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: I would recommend adding a default image in a seed file. Alternatively it might be a better idea to set the default image in your application code. CarrierWave probably deals with that - try search the readme for setting a default.

Comment: I didn't know the existence of `seed`. It seems better that my first idea. Thank you.